# Minecraftのマルチサーバについて

Tags: nginx

現在グローバルIP一つでマルチサーバを立てているのですがもう一台サーバを建てたいと思っています
そこでリバースプロキシを使ってドメインでサーバを分けようかと思っているのですがどうにもうまく行きません

使用ソフト nginx (リバースプロキシ）

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 各サーバーのリッスンポートを分ければいいのでは

Answer (score 2):

一般に、リバースプロキシと呼ばれるものはHTTP(S)サーバとして動作し、後段のHTTP(S)サーバーに通信を中継します。一方、ゲームのマルチプレイ用サーバは独自のプロトコルを使ったものが多いです。Minecraftもそうです。ですからMinecraftのプロトコルに対応していないNginxは正しく通信を中継することができません。

また、ドメインからIPアドレスへの変換はクライアント側で行われるので、HTTPのように接続先のドメインを送信するようなプロトコルでなければ、どのドメインとしてアクセスされたかを判別することはできません。

Minecraftのサーバーを一つのIPアドレスで複数運用したいのであれば、コメントで指摘されているように別ポートで起動することになります。

例: [マインクラフトの複数サーバー同時起動について。現在ポート開... - Yahoo!知恵袋](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11144191091)